# How to store text with special characters in php?

Tags: php

My description paragraph contains ("" and ') but when I try to save data, slash(\) get saved in database before these characters. I am using `mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['des'],$link);` but that is not working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you're double-escaping your data. This would be the case if magic quotes are enabled. You can check for this by examining the return value of `gpc_magic_quotes_enabled()`.

If magic quotes are enabled, you should turn them off in your php.ini, or unescape your data with [`stripslashes`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.stripslashes.php) before you use it.

Answer (score 0):

Check your `php.ini` settings for `magic_quotes_gpc` and `magic_quotes_runtime`. Turn them off.